# I recently read about unit of work and repository design patterns; working with EF wondering if this is a good design pattern

Tags: design, design-patterns, entity-framework

I found myself creating child records that require a master record to exist, first, so that they can reference it by the master record's primary key (if that's the right term).

To accomplish this using EF 6 I tried to call `SaveChanges()` twice - once to create the master record so that its identity key gets generated and once after the children have been created.

The problem I ran into was that EF doesn't like multiple calls to `SaveChanges()` so I had to use a transaction.  I don't like using a transaction because it feels messy for some reason I can't articulate.

It's a somewhat common problem for me to have to do this so instead of a `using`, `try/catch` and `commit/rollback` I figured it'd be easier to have this each time:

```
this._dbContextWrapper.CommitIfTrue(() =>
{
    // Multiple calls to SaveChanges() here

    return true;
});
```

While also having `BeginTransaction()` exposed on my `_dbContextWrapper` so that if passing a `Func<bool>` isn't desirable.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<TModel> Query<TModel>()
        where TModel : class;

    TModel Find<TModel>(params object[] key)
        where TModel : class;

    void Add<TModel>(TModel model)
        where TModel : class;

    void Update<TModel>(TModel updated, params object[] key) 
        where TModel : class;

    IDataResult SaveChanges();

    void Delete<TModel>(params object[] key)
        where TModel : class;

    IRepositoryTransaction BeginTransaction();

    IRepositoryTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);

    IDataResult CommitIfTrue(Func<bool> transaction);

    IDataResult CommitIfTrue(Func<bool> transaction, IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
}

public interface IRepositoryTransaction : IDisposable
{  
    void Commit();

    void Rollback();
}

public interface IDataResult
{
    bool IsSuccess { get; }

    string ErrorMessage { get; }
}
```

I realize that this "`IRepository`" only a thin wrapper around `DbContext` - I'm doing it so that my classes can have a `Mock` implementation provided to them instead of having to mess with `Fakes` to get around the non-virtual aspect of `DbContext`'s methods.

My question is:

**Is my `CommitIfTrue` method reasonable?  Is there a way to do something similar that's also more testable/involves no `Action`s or `Func`s?**

Comment: With EF you can add master and child records in the same unit of work. Also, " I don't like using a transaction because it feels messy for some reason I can't articulate" - you probably want to work on that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it would need to return true. Why couldn't it simply commit if no exception is thrown? That's the way it would be if you just had a transaction in a `using` statement. There are arguments for and against external vs. internal control of these types of things (ie. external vs internal iteration), but I don't see the need to have BOTH `CommitIfTrue()` and `BeginTransaction()`. They essentially provide the same functionality.

Comment: That part (returning a bool) felt clunky after I used it (whichc didn't happen until after I wrote this).  But I've changed it - it's now just an `Action` - not a `Func<bool>`.  Do you think there's a testability issue?  Well BeginTransaction gives you access to the `IDisposable` transaction object meaning you can choose to use it outside the context of a single method or `using` block and dispose of it yourself.  It's just more typing, hence the `Commit` overload.